# li element border too big

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to style an unordered list with the following elements:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.bullet li {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px cyan;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="margin-left: 28px;">I make awesome stuffs with</h2>
<ul class="bullet">
  <li>Python</li>
  <li>HTML</li>
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>Javascript</li>
  <li>Node.js</li>
  <li>Unix shell scripting</li>
</ul>
```

The borders on the list elements go upto the extreme right of the page like so -

[image: Rendered list]

Can anyone please guide me on how I can reduce the border size so that it wraps around the word only.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This's exactly what you need bro...

**HTML**

```
<h2 style="margin-left: 28px;">I make awesome stuffs with</h2>
<ul class="bullet">
    <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unix shell scripting</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.bullet li{
    list-style: none;
}

ul.bullet li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px cyan;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `<span>` tag? Note that when you apply styling to the `<li>` tag you must understand that its size is not limited to the text you insert in it.

```css
 ul{
    list-style: none;
    }

    ul.bullet li {
        list-style-position: inside;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
   

    ul.bullet li span {
        border: solid 1px cyan;
        padding:5px;
        margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="margin-left: 28px;">I make awesome stuffs with</h2>
<ul class="bullet">
  <li><span>Python</span></li>
  <li><span>HTML</span></li>
    <li><span>CSS</span></li>
    <li><span>Javascript</span></li>
    <li><span>Node.js</span></li>
    <li><span>Unix shell scripting</span></li>
</ul>
```